# output of the who command

Tags: terminal, macos, command-line

I am trying to understand the output of the `who` command. When I add the `-H` flag to print the headers, the second column ( the one signifying the users logged in) is titled `LINE`. I am trying to understand what `LINE` is. I am logged into my computer twice, according to the `who` command, but one of the lines is bad. To understand what that means, I would like to know what `LINE` is.

Comment: See [What is the exact difference between a ‘terminal’, a ‘shell’, a ‘tty’ and a ‘console’?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con) over @ Unix/Linux SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINE indicates the TTY the process is running on. It is correct about you being logged into your computer twice, as you are logged in once to Cocoa (the OS X desktop), `console`, full path: `/dev/console`, and again in the terminal, `ttysXXX`, full path: `/dev/ttysXXX` (where "XXX" is a three-digit number, starting from 001).

`console` is Darwin's (OS X kernel) only 'real' TTY, the only one that isn't running in a terminal emulator. `console`, being the only non-emulated TTY is therefore the only one GUIs can run on.

The Apple logo that appears when Cocoa is not running (booting and shut-down) is generated by the kernel except when in verbose mode (start the Mac with the boot argument -V either by holding ctrl-V while booting or running `nvram boot-args="-v"` as root, however that will make your Mac always boot in verbose mode until you run `nvram boot-args=""` or clear nvram).

When boot in verbose mode instead of an Apple logo the kernel will log any boot messages and related to `/dev/console` and anything written to `/dev/console` will show up on the console and therefore on-screen (since nothing is generating a GUI on it, whether that be Cocoa or the Kernel). The main part of this is how other Unix-like/POSIX systems work.

I know this answer is kind of crappy but I hope it helps.